# Unable to use pgmail

Tags: postgresql

Does anyone use pgmail?

In order to use it, I need to first install postgresql-tcl. However, even after installing it on postgresql-12 - while running below command:

```
    CREATE EXTENSION pltcl;
```

I'm getting below error:

```
   ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/pgsql-12/share/extension/pltcl.control": No 
   such file or directory
```

What I have tried:

I followed https://tunnelix.com/messing-around-pltcl-on-postgresql/ and instead of CREATE EXTENSION , I used  CREATE LANGUAGE. However, I again I got below error:

```
  shiwangini1=#  CREATE language pltcl;
  ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pltcl": No such file or directory
```

What else can I do to make it working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You made a mistake installing the software. Either you didn't install it, or you installed it in a wrong directory. Perhaps the wrong package?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - I used this syntax for installation: yum install postgresql12-tcl

Comment: Perhaps you mixed installation packages from different sources.

Comment: any way to figure out and get it fixed?

Comment: Start with a list of the installed PostgreSQL software packages.